# Two Symfony Projects in same domain

Tags: git, .htaccess, symfony

I'm having some trouble with staging Symfony application. I have two main branches on GIT (production and preproduction)

The production environment is deployed on the web root (**mydomaine.com**), I want to know what's the best way to deploy the preproduction environment on the same domaine knowing that :

- I do not have the possibility to create a subdomaine
- The preproduction have some code that cannot be deployed on production, and uses a different database connecion
- Ideally, the preproduction would be accessible via **mydomaine.com/preproduction**

I have tried doing this, but I always get this error on the production prod.log :

> No route found for "GET /preproduction/

- Added /web/preproduction to .gitignore
- Performed a git clone on branch preproduction inside /web/preproduction (so basically */web/preproduction* is a copy of the project but on the branch preproduction
- Added all possible rewrite conditions and rules in /web/.htaccess to ignore all /web/preproduction requests from the production front controller (/web/app.php) and redirect them to the preproduction front controller (/web/preproduction/web/app.php) but none of my attempts was successful

This is the modified /web/.htaccess file :

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>    
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/preproduction
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/preproduction/web/app.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/preproduction
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Putting a whole Symfony project inside web/ seems messy. Can't you use different folders and simply use `Alias` in your vHost/Rewrite?

Comment: And the Alias would point to a subfolder ? or a subdomain ? If it's about a subfolder this is what i'm trying to do : production front controller is always catching the requests, and never ignore them "No route found for "GET /preproduction/"